# Why does twocolumn mode break usage of \AtBeginDocument{}?

Tags: macros, titles

I've been happily using the `multicol` package to layout a set of documents that are generated for multiple output formats from the same source. By necessity this moves same code from the document source to a style file. For example I need to be able to make the choice to prepend a title or not from the style package. Instead of:

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

I need to be able to run the equivalent of:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle}
\begin{document}
```

This seems simple enough, but `multicol` wreaks havoc on breaking `mdframed` boxes and [apparently there is no way to fix that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235613/5100). So I've been trying to adapt to using the `twocolumn` layout mode instead. This fixes the box breaking issues, but introduces new ones. First up I tried adding the option to my `geometry` package, which I was already using. This had the odd effect of putting my title inside a column, which is not what I was after:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[twocolumn]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image: geomentry columns]

So I tried using the option of the document class instead.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

This produces an error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \begin{document}

Strangely, running `\maketitle` manually solves this error:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\AtBeginDocument{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image: documentclass columns]

And in this version my title spans the columns like I want it to, but of course I can't properly control in which editions there should be a title in the first place, which makes it useless to me.

How can I either ① set the columns with `geometry` but have the title span both columns or ② set them with the document class options but still be able to use `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument` still does code not meant for typesetting, before `\begin{document}.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\AtBeginDocument` is the wrong hook for typeset material. This hook is still executed in the preamble. Package `etoolbox` provides `\AfterEndPreamble`, which is executed at the very end of `\begin{document}`, thus document material is allowed here:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\AfterEndPreamble{\maketitle}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use `\xapptocmd` from `xpatch` package to **append** some command after `\begin{document}` (short form `\document`)

`\AtBeginDocument` is not meant for typesetting material stuff since it expands code **before** `\begin{document}` comes into *action*

Another approach is shown in the answer by Heiko Oberdiek.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
%\AtBeginDocument{\maketitle}
\xapptocmd{\document}{\maketitle}{}{}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```